# Long running scheduler throws exception accessing jpa/ejb object

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, websphere

I have a scheduler object to do some errands.
It looks like this

```
@Singleton
public class BackgroundScheduler
{
    @EJB(beanName = "myPersistenceService")
    private PersistenceService dbService;   //persistence object to do some db inserts


    //runs every 30 minutes 
    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/30", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void BackgroundJob()
    {
        logger.debug("Waking up to do to chores");
        DoChores();
    }

    private void DoChores()
    {
        entityObj entity;
        //do some stuff here
        doStuff();

        //write to db
        dbService.writeStuff(entity);
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as doStuff() is done in 5 minutes. When doStuff() takes more than that, I get an exception at dbService.writeStuff(entity)

```
[9/24/19 20:35:09:993 EDT] 000000b6 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "writeStuff" on bean "BeanId(MYAPPEJB.jar#myPersistenceService, null)". Exception data: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId=MYAPPEJB.jar#APPCMN
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:233)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:143)
```

I tried @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) on both (BackgroundScheduler and myPersistenceService).
I have set "Total Transaction lifetime timeout" (Application servers<>transaction service) to 0.
I also tried setting connection pool timeout to 0.

I am out of ideas as to which timeout settings is causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you set "total transaction lifetime timeout" to 0, it then defers to the "maximum transaction timeout" which has default of 300 seconds, or 5 minutes.  Refer to this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/udat_contranserv.html).  Try increasing this value.

Comment: When the scheduler is working on a long task, I do see this message [9/25/19 11:41:41:612 EDT] 000000b4 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0" (000000b0) has been active for 701596 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:127)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)

Comment: WSVR0605W is a message that the server puts out by default to notify that a thread that has been running for a long time might be hung.  The server has no way of knowing if you intended it to take that long or not.  When it's expected behavior for it to take a long time because it's actually doing a lot of work (it sounds like that is the case here) there is a way to adjust the threshold at which the warning is logged.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ttrb_confighangdet.html